# Domain forwarding with url substitution in the address bar

Tags: domains, url-rewriting, masking

I have a blog being served by a machine I have at home. Since the ip can change i set up a dyndns domain to always point to that machine. However, I purchased a more friendly domain (at godaddy.com) and I would like to forward it to that blog. The problem is that if I simply forward it the users will see the dyndns domain in the address bar and could potentially bookmark those urls and that's a problem.

I noticed that godaddy.com  has domain masking and although it does hide the dyndns domain in the address bar, it also keeps the same root address in the address bar even if I navigate to another page. I also have the feeling that search engines will not like this domain masking thing.

Does anyone know how can I accomplish what I want?

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/what-is-domain-masking-or-cloaking-why-should-it-be-avoided-for-a-new-web-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.yoursite.com. CNAME yourdyndns.dyndns.org

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you, I was completely unaware of this option. Thank you!!

Comment: One question though, is this solution search engine friendly?

Comment: as friendly as an A/AAAA is

Answer (score 1):

If you're using dynamic DNS for your webserver you won't be able to do this is a search engine friendly way. You either have to accept the one domain in the address bar, which means a frame is used and frames are not search engine friendly, or have them see the dynamic domain in the address bar. If you want to use your own domain name with real URLs get a static IP address or host it on a remote webserver.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Besides the fact that is not search engine friendly, what also annoys me about the domain masking is the fact that the url in the address bar doesn't change when the user navigates to another page.